# Columns not merging correctly. Not overwriting blank columns

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

When merging .xlsx files/sheets in python, it puts the data below empty columns.
See example below

I've tried several different ways to merge the files but all of them merge them this way.

```
excel_files= [src_code,dst_code]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in excel_files])
df.to_csv(filtered_comb_excel,index=False)

      ColumnA             ColumnB       ColumnC       ColumnD
       Data                Data 
       DAta                Data          
       DAta                Data          
                                         Data          DAta
                                         Data          Data
```

One file has data in column A and B, the other file has data in column C and D.
I essentially want column C put into column C starting from row 1, the same with A,B, and D:

```
 ColumnA             ColumnB       ColumnC       ColumnD
       Data            Data         Data          Data
       DAta            Data         Data          Data
       DAta            Data         DAta          DAta
```

Comment: try `pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).reset_index(drop=True) for f in excel_files], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `reset_index` then concat with `axis=1`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).reset_index(drop=True) for f in excel_files],axis=1)
```

Comment: Looks like it worked. There are a few oddities I need to look into now and see if it's related to my other code. Ex: Data being put in columns, C,D,E,F, with headers in A,B,G,H, instead of just putting the data in A,B,C,D.
It also looks like data may be missing from the first row from the source Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframes have a unique key you could try:

```
 df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='key'), excel_files)
```

or some variation base you your df

```
 df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,right_on='rightkey', left_on='leftkey'), excel_files)
```

Not sure without seeing the dfs.